# automated deployment on production with puppet

Tags: puppet, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I would like to know how automated deployment to production works with puppet.

Do I need a puppet-slave on my production server? If thats the case, is that insecure and what rights do puppet get with that?

A use-case could be to get a package from a repository manager and then to deploy it to the production server. What are the main steps on this way with puppet?

Comment: try asking this on serverfault. here is a similar discussion: http://serverfault.com/questions/371172/can-any-puppet-agent-get-any-puppet-file-from-the-master

Answer (score 0):

Puppet can run in solo-mode where you apply a set of configurations in config file on the host in which you run it, as long as puppet (client/agent) is already installed there.

You can also run puppet in a client-server mode, where an agent runs on your production server and obtains configuration details from a puppet server (or puppet master)

`If you run in client-server mode, how do you ensure security?`

Well, in client-server mode, you pre-register a client/agent to a server you nominate and the exchange ssl certificates before any actions can be applied on that agent.  Again, you would have to (on your pupper server or master)  associate a set of actions or manifests to the production server running the agent.  I suppose that provides sufficient security, assuming you already took care of standard OS security for both systems in the first instance.

Also, additional security can be provided by the puppet file server as suggested in the link suggested by bagheera.  If you are even more paranoid than that, then you would need to consider using [puppet librarian](http://librarian-puppet.com/) with a Puppetfile that is assembled and used at run time.

`In either case, the bigger challenge for you is that the set of instructions (or manifests) applied have undergone testing (on a test or staging server) before being applied to a production system.`

So, you need to be sure what you are doing when you start trying to apply puppet manifests to production servers.  I would not recommend just downloading puppet modules and using them without a decent insight into what you are doing and a clear understanding of what each module you intend to use does.

[Puppetlabs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/) have great introduction documentation for using puppet, and that would be an excellent place to start learning more about puppet.  A good book would also be useful.